# Non-uniformly integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

So I need to show that the sequence $f_{n} = nI_{(0,1/n)} - nI_{(1/n,2/n)}$ is integrable in the limit but not uniformly integrable. I was able to show the first part and know that $g_n = nI_{(0,1/n)}$ is not uniformly integrable by consider 
$$
\sup_{n}\int_{[|g_n| > \alpha]}|g_n|d\mu
$$ which equals 1 when $\alpha < n$.
However, I don't know how to show for $f_n$.

Comment: What does "integrable in the limit" mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it means $Ef_n = 0$ a.e.

Comment: Huh? What does "$Ef_n=0$ almost everywhere" mean??? (For that to make any sense, $Ef_n$ has to be a _function_; I can't imagine what function you're referring to with that notation)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm sorry for my sloppy notation, it means that $Ef_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ gets large.

Comment: @Harry Do you need further explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|f_n|=nI_{(0,1/n)} + nI_{(1/n,2/n)} >\alpha$ for $0<\alpha<n$ on both intervals $(0,1/n)$ and $(1/n,2/n)$, so $$\int_{[|f_n| > \alpha]}|f_n|d\mu=2$$